# Quick collection for a look up in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a the following requirement to develop and am wondering what the fastest collection I could use in .net would be.

"To search a static collection of strings to find all string that start with a given string, the string can be in order".

Would a hashtable be the best to use? This is being done in c# .net 4.0.

Thanks

Comment: Premature optimization anyone? Use whatever is most convenient - change it if performance becomes a problem and profiling identified the collection type as the culprit.

Comment: @Oded That should be an answer. I'd upvote it. This stinks of homework, though.

Comment: How big do you expect this list to be?  In the millions?  A List<string> should suffice otherwise :)

Comment: I doubt a hashtable would be appropriate.  The problem is you are asking for something that is very subjective, and depends on given requirements, that you did not provide.

Comment: @Polynomial - Fair enough. Added an answer.

Comment: `HashTable` won't provide any benefit if you're not comparing the whole `string` (the question suggests you're querying for a prefix).

Answer (score 3):

It is premature to optimize collection types - you don't even have working code!

Use a convenient collection type (`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, `List<Tuple<T1,T2>>` or whatever) - once you have working code, if there is a performance problem:

- Profile the code
- Identify the hotspots
- If the collection you have selected is a hotspot, consider changing it.
- Profile after the change to see you have fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

To find strings with a given prefix quickly, try a [**trie**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

[image: Trie dictionary sample]